# How to change arrow position in select tag?

Tags: html, css

I faced a problem when styling the select tag. The thing is that by default, the arrow is in the right corner of the field, which takes the size of the largest option tag. That's why, when a small option is selected, everything looks not in a proper way. Is there any possibility to adjust the width of the select tag to the current option or somehow attach the arrow to it? Thanks in advance!

Show screen:

[image: Show screen]

### Code:

```css
.module-table {
    min-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;    
}
.module-status-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; 
    border: none; 
    background: transparent;
    margin-left: -4px;
}
option {
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<table class="module-table">
    <tr>
        ...
    </tr>
    ...

    <tr>
        ...
        <td>
            <select class="module-status-dropdown module-status-dropdown-rejected">
                <option value="rejected">Rejected</option>
                <option value="pending">Pending</option>
                <option value="approved">Approved</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="module-status-dropdown">
                <option value="rejected">Waiting for payment</option>
                <option value="pending">Paid</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

I tried applying the appearance: none property and adding an arrow using the after pseudo element, but nothing worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I style a <select> dropdown with only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-do-i-style-a-select-dropdown-with-only-css)

Comment: Please add your code so we can see what you actually want.

Comment: You can set a width to your select field, like to any other element.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different option is to place the arrow to the left of the text to give the user a consistent experience, regardless of the text width.

This can be achieved by using the CSS direction property.

```css
select {
  direction: rtl;
}

option {
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="rejected">Waiting for payment</option>
  <option value="pending">Paid</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using `-webkit-apperarance` and the `background-image` property:

```html
<select>
    <option selected>Option 1</option>
    <option disabled>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>       
</select>
```

```css
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/lqNaWae.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
    padding: 4px;
    -webkit-padding-end: 30px;
}
```

**Workaround for padding in the dropdown image:**

As far as I searched, I didn't find any straightforward solution to provide some space to make the custom arrow icon padded, but I found a workaround for the same, that is using `background-position-x` to move it away from edges. Here is an implementation:

```css
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/lqNaWae.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
    padding: 6px;
    background-position-x: 90%
    -webkit-padding-end: 20px;
}
```

### **View:**

[image]

Comment: Yes, but the arrow will be at the very right edge again, and if you select the short option, the gap will be too big, as in the screenshot. Is it not possible to link it to the text somehow?

Comment: Hi @EvgenyNonin , I have updated the solution with a workaround. Let me know if this is what you were expecting